# Interface's manual configuration problem

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

I'm building some home lab (Linux & windows) & I have some very basic configuration problems.

The problem:
Ubuntu 14.04 updated & upgraded (will be a router)

I want to configure 3 interfaces & apply IP & MAC this way

- first one (`eth0`) Bridged to the ISP with HW ADDR ex: `D0:D0:D0:D0:D0:00` & IP given from my Box
- second one (`eth1`) on a LAN Segment with HW ADDR ex: `D0:D0:D0:D0:D0:01` & IP `10.10.10.254/24`
- third one (`eth2`) on a LAN Segment with HW ADDR ex: `D0:D0:D0:D0:D0:02` & IP `10.10.11.254/24`

I apply this in interface file for `eth1 & 2`.

```
# interface LAN_10
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address         10.10.10.254
        netmask         255.255.255.0
        broadcast       10.10.10.255
        network         10.10.10.0
        hwaddress ether D0:D0:D0:D0:D0:01
```

for `eth0` as it is bridged to the Box. It is getting a DHCP IP which is OK for now. But I would like to apply on it manually only the HW ADDR `D0:D0:D0:D0:D0:00` for `eth0` and later for an IP, but that's for later.

When I do all of this `ipconfig -a` gives me a `mismatched & mixed` relations of HWADDR & IP

ex:

```
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D0:D0:D0:D0:D0:01  
              inet addr:10.10.11.254  Bcast:10.10.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe42:a002/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:15000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8355 (8.3 KB)
              Interrupt:17 Base address:0x2080
```

Where is this mismatch coming from?

Which has more precedence, Network Manager graphical tool or `/etc/network/interface` file?

If I do different (it is not the case) in those modes which one will be set up?

Worst of all sometimes the `/etc/network/interface` file is not even considered and I lose the connectivity.

I found on your forum [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510025/ubuntu-14-04-lts-network-manager-overwrites-static-network-interface) and the need of get rid of the two `if...fi` blocks in pre-start and post-stop in `/etc/init/networking.conf` but I'm not sure of what I'm doing any more and where I'm getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let's turn it other way ... if I only want to change the HW ADDR of a unique eth0 served by an dhcp server.
Which file should I modify ? the same one (etc/network/interface)
cause in there will be only 
auto eth0
init dhcp

...

anybody ?